# Why is the MapListener not always fired on Codename One GoogleMap under Simulator

Tags: codenameone

My app features a `ContainerMap` (GoogleMap with valid Javascript API Key) that is laid in center location of a BorderLayout form.

```
super(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE));
...
this.add(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER, BorderLayout.center(userReportsMap));
```

I have registered a `MapListener` and I wonder why it is not always fired when I zoom in or out under simulator ? It looks like it is fired a dozen of times right at the beginning when the GoogleMap is initialized and the MapListener is added to the map, and then it does not fire anymore. I press minus key and plus key to zoom out and in.

Please note : I don't remove the listener or instantiate the map anywhere afterwards.

On  the contrary on an Android device it seems to work as expected when I pinch. So is it a limitation in the simulator due to the underlying Javascript map ?

Any hint appreciated,

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the JavaScript version of the map which is relatively new. I would suggest filing an issue with a test case on the project.

Answer (score 1):

I have just released some changes to the Google Maps lib to fix a couple of race conditions in JS and simulator.  This might fix the issue for you.

[here](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/blob/master/GoogleMaps.cn1lib) is a direct link to latest lib.  Or you can wait (probably less than a day) for it to appear in Codename One Settings/Extensions and update through there.

Comment: Sorry Steve but I barely see any difference. I added a `System.err.println` within the `MapListener()` and it does not print anything whenever I zoom in/out (with -/+ keys) or move the map. I am using GoogleMaps version 14. Is it the one you were talking about ?

Comment: I would add that to my mind it is even worse since the MapListener does not seem to get fired at all (on simulator as well as on the device).

Comment: You'll need to file an issue and provide a test case.  My test app is firing the map change events to the MapListener correctly in simulator and on all devices I have tried (Android, iOS).  This has been working for me in all versions.  Version number should be up to 15 though.

Comment: That's weird, there should be an error on my side. Otherwise the CN1 extensions window shows me a green tick while libs/GoogleMaps.ver still shows `version=14`.

Comment: Now it shows version 15! However if you add `        cnt.addMapListener((source, zoom, center) -> {
            System.err.println("Zoom or center changed");
        });` on line 185 of your test case (#2011) , the message is only printed twice in the beginning and never afterwards (at least in the simulator).

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce.  Make sure your project CN1 plugin is up to date, and your project libs are up to date.  There were some relatively recent (~1.5 months ago) changes to the javascript bridge that may affect this.

Comment: The preferences menu shows 1.21 in the title bar, and NetBeans does not offer me any update. CN1libs have been refreshed many times also. Is my version up to date ?

Comment: It looks that the issue on my system is coming from the Skins. I reset the skins, it showed the iphone3 skins where the mapListener is behaving correctly. However I downloaded other skins like Iphone6, Xoom, SamsungS7, GoogleNexus7, but the issue still remains. Only HTC10 (along with iphone3G) is working as expected.

Comment: I still can't reproduce. I'll need a test case to investigate further.