# How to correctly use BoundingBox getNE and getSW in Codename One

Tags: google-maps, codenameone

My app features a `MapContainer` on which I want to draw a marker for each report in the database. As there could be thousands of reports simultaneously in the database and as many users of my app, I want to always add markers for the reports that can be displayed on the map area actually displayed.

That's why I only ask the database for records that lay within South West and North East bounds. On simulator it works great, the reports are plotted  where they should on the map.

I get the NE and SW bounds with the following commands :

```
MapContainer googleMap = new MapContainer("MyGoogleMapsKeyForJavaScript");
Coord NE = googleMap.getBoundingBox().getNorthEast();
Coord SW = googleMap.getBoundingBox().getSouthWest();
```

However on the actual device (Android 4.4) the records are not retrieved because the device asks for reports within bounds that are ouside France (where the app is intended to be used).

So for example, the device shows a map centered on France, where I can also see Spain, Portugal, Italy, Belgien, a part of Germany. To sum up, the map shows western Europe (see screen capture below where the MapContainer is circled in red).

[image]

Now if I display the NE and SW coordinates, the NE is somewhere in Libya and the SW somewhere in Guinea (see below where the NE and SW bounds have been manually added to the map). So the bounding box is in Afrika, and does not embrace the location I see on the map.

[image]

Consequently as the bounding box has nothing to do with the map displayed, the database cannot retrieve records in Afrika when all records are in France.

Moreover the more I zoom in the more the map goes northern. I don't display the zoom but actually when I zoom to a very high level (18+ I guess) then the report appear on the map. But I have to zoom exactly where I know the report is, whereas on the simulator, the reports are plotted everytime they lay in the bounding box (which seems correct although I cannot display the value because of [the other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42880326/why-is-the-maplistener-not-always-fired-on-codename-one-googlemap-under-simulato) I encounter).

Did I make a mistake in my understanding of how to use NE / SW bounds, why is it working in the simulator but not on the real device ? Or is it just a bug on this specific device and it won't happen on more modern devices ?

Any lights shed on this issue would help a lot,

Comment: If I understand correctly the values for NE/SW are correct but the map positioning/zoom is incorrect as the map shows too much of the region. Right?
Did you move the camera besides doing zoom?  One of the strategies I know people used is to move the camera and zoom dynamically until the bounding box is within a good region since zoom values might differ between platforms.

Comment: Hi Shai, what I meant was the opposite : the map is correct but the NE/SE aren't. But you may be on the right track! Indeed I only zoom with the user location as center. I will try to move  the camera also.

Comment: @Shai, I added illustrations to make it clearer. Does it bring you another idea ?

Comment: Steve added that feature, I'll ask him to take a look as my brain is in stutter mode due to work overload...

Comment: I reviewed the code and removed every zoom calls (which were of no use actually) and kept only a single call to `setCameraPosition` to center the map on the user when the user presses a button. However the NE SW on the device are still different from what I expect and see in the simulator.

Comment: @Shai thanks and keep cool :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the bounding box before the MapContainer has been added to the UI will yield undefined results.  The bounding box is the bounds of the Map that are visible in the UI.  Until the map has been added to the UI, we don't know what the bounds will be...

Comment: Thanks Steve for your answer. But why is it working on the simulator ? And also I understand that the first time I ask for the bounds the Map is not already laid out, but for the next calls it is because the form has been completely laid out. Maybe I've missed your point. Are you saying the : 1) creating a new  MapContainer, then 2) add it to the form and eventually 3) ask for the bounding box, should work for sure ?

Comment: You were right. Indeed I was calling indirectly (ie through a method of mine) the `zoom()` method.before the `MapContainer` was laid out in the form. I removed this call and the value became as expected!